# Mongoose Middleware findOneAndUpdate Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have used aes-256 to encrypt my values and saved in DB. I have used pre and post mongoose middleware to encrypt before POST and decrypt before GET. I have a scenario to findOneAndUpdate. For that I need to decrypt the mongoose value of the condition but I have no idea how to do it.

**Encrypt POST data**

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var data = Encrypt(this);
this.phone = data.phone //asded324ffdsf
}
```

**Decrypt GET data**

```
userSchema.post('findOne', function (document) {
  var data = Decrypt(document);
  if(document.phone){
    document.phone = data.phone; //123456780
  }
});
```

Requirement

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({phone:'1234567890'},{ $set: { pwd_token: random } }); //Query fails as the number is asded324ffdsf
```

How do I decrypt the phone number from my DB and compare here with the given number ?

What should I do in userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (document) {} ?

Comment: Could you please specify the correct `.findOneAndUpdate()` query you want to perform? The one you stated above is incorrect. It has to have filter and payload objects

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you cannot access the document being updated in `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` query middleware. In order to access the document, you need to execute an explicit query for the document.

Refer to the documentation for more info: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes